# Want to set state once on first render without causing uneccessary re-renders on further updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

I have a `MarketOverview` component that renders a bunch of cryptocurrency trading pair markets. On initialisation, I want it to render the `BTC/USD` market by default, which I'm doing via `useEffect()`. The problem is the `defaultMarket` gets called on every render. Moreover, `defaultMarket` depends on the `tickers` prop, so if I wrap it in `useMemo()`, then the eslint react-hooks plugin automatically populates `tickers` as a dependency.

Without `useMemo()`:

```
const defaultMarket = tickers.find((ticker) => {
    return ticker.market_id === "BTC-USD";
  });
```

With `useMemo()`:

```
const defaultMarket = useMemo(
    () =>
      tickers.find((ticker) => {
        return ticker.market_id === "BTC-USD";
      }),
    [tickers]
  );
```

Entire component:

```
export const MarketOverview = memo(({ tickers }: TProps) => {

  // Set default market on initialisation to BTC/USD
  const defaultMarket = tickers.find((ticker) => {
    return ticker.market_id === "BTC-USD";
  });

  const [selectedMarket, setSelectedMarket] = useState<ITicker | undefined>(
    undefined
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedMarket(defaultMarket);
  }, [defaultMarket]);

  // Select market
  const selectMarket = (market: ITicker) => {
    history.push(`${PUBLIC_URL}/markets/${market.market_id}`);
    setSelectedMarket(market);
  };
  return (
    <div className="market-overview-container">
      <MarketSelector
        tickers={tickers}
        selectMarket={selectMarket}
        selectedMarket={selectedMarket}
      />
      {selectedMarket && <MarketStats selectedMarket={selectedMarket} />}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, then you'll never recompute `defaultMarket` if `tickers` ever updates.

If you really want to though, you can add an eslint disable for the line and use an empty dependency array so the hook runs once only on component mount.

```
const defaultMarket = useMemo(
  () =>
    tickers.find((ticker) => {
      return ticker.market_id === "BTC-USD";
    }),
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  []
);
```