# Specifying dependencies in useEffect component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am using the React `useEffect` hook along with Redux. My action creator runs for the first time following the first render, as i specify the `[]` as the second argument of useEffect. The action involves reaching out to an API to get some data back.

The redux state object `storeItems` then updates and everything is fine. However, I am getting the eslint warning `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'.`. I don't want to specify the second argument as `[props]` as this will cause a second run of useEffect, which means a needless reach out to an API. Does anyone have a way to get rid of this warning without specifying the second argument as `[props]`?

```
function GetStoreData(props){
    useEffect(() => {
        props.getStoreItems()
        console.log(props.storeItems)
    }, []);

    return null
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {storeItems: state.storeItems};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getStoreItems: getStoreItems})(GetStoreData);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to set state once on first render without causing uneccessary re-renders on further updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057343/want-to-set-state-once-on-first-render-without-causing-uneccessary-re-renders-on)